# ESLint complaining about ESLint plugins not being installed in a monorepo

Tags: eslint

In a monorepo setup I get errors for having some ESLint plugins not being  installed while I don't have those plugins listed in my `plugins` array.

My project have a few packages under `packages/**`

```
yarn lint
yarn run v1.15.2
$ eslint --config .eslintrc ./

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 5.16.0.
ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-airbnb". This can happen for a couple different reasons:

1. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure eslint-plugin-airbnb is also installed globally. A globally-installed ESLint cannot find a locally-installed plugin.

2. If ESLint is installed locally, then it's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

    npm i eslint-plugin-airbnb@latest --save-dev

Path to ESLint package: /mnt/airlab/repos/one/node_modules/eslint

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint to chat with the team.

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs because some packages ship their `.eslintrc` file with them and ESLint is picking up those configs when running it. By default ESLint ignores all configs in `node_modules` but if you have an `.eslintignore` you should add a line for ignoring deep node_modules folders so those stray configs are not picked up.

**`.eslintignore`**

```
packages/**/node_modules
```